# How to replace matches using Regexp::Grammars?

Tags: regex, perl, regexp-grammars

I am using `Regexp::Grammars` to search and extract information from a complex textual source, but ultimately I want to also make replacements on that source.  Is there a way to accomplish this either directly or indirectly using `Regexp::Grammars`?

For example, suppose I have the following definition:

```
use Regexp::Grammars;
qr {
    <[element]>*

    <rule: element> 
        <target> | <word> | <bracket>

    <rule: target> 
        <define> \( (<word>)* \)

    <token: define>
        define

    <token: word>
        \w+

    <token: bracket>
        [()]
}xm
```

How would I replace all `<target>`s with some replacement that is say a function of the `<word>` between the brackets?

Comment: I doubt that's possible, but if you ask Damian directly I am sure we are in for a nice talk at the next Perl Conference. :)

Comment: Would Autoactions or Parse-time data processing help? Something along the lines where the method called by target would manage the required replacement? Challenge is how to get the un-affected part of the input string to the output without too much clutter.